# Replacing invalid XML 1.0 characters with Kotlin

Tags: xml, kotlin, replace, replaceall

I am working with Kotlin code that publishes to a legacy system that cannot handle any special character in XML 1.0.

In Java...I can use ReplaceAll to accomplish.....in Kotlin, I believe I need to use Regex, but unsure if my pattern string will work.

Thoughts on a solution?

Java

```
String pattern = "[^"+ "\u0009\r\n"
               + "\u0020-\uD7FF"
                + "\uE000-\uFFFD"
                + "\ud800\udc00-\udbff\udfff"
                + "]";

String result = thestring.replaceAll(pattern, "");
```

Kotlin????

```
str pattern = "[^"+ "\u0009\r\n"
               + "\u0020-\uD7FF"
                + "\uE000-\uFFFD"
                + "\ud800\udc00-\udbff\udfff"
                + "]";
str = str.replace(Regex(pattern), "")
```

Comment: If the legacy system actually handles XML, it can handle any special characters that might be in there. Can you describe more closely what the legacy system does?

Comment: It is external but throws an exception for invalid XML characters...we cannot get access to the logs..actually built a hack sanitize function to work around it, but that is not right and are just adding as we run into issues.  We know the patterns of characters we need to remove for 1.0 compatibility so trying to replicate what I do in Java...description.replace("&","").replace("½","").replace("\"","").replace("<","").replace(">","").replace("\u00AE","").replace("\u00A9","").replace("\u2122","").replace("é","").replace("&#232","").replace("è","").replace("\u00E8","")

Comment: Are you sure you are saving the XML file in the correct file encoding, i.e. the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="..."?>` and the actual encoding of the file are in agreement?

Comment: See above, not a file, string API call to a .NET service...no encoding...returns generic 500 internal exception, can't change their service (which is unfortunate) so trying to work within that constraint

Comment: So it's a HTTP web service? Are you sure that the `Content-Type` header you send in your request and the byte encoding of the request payload are in agreement?